# Iptable with google cloud load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Because incoming traffic cost , my care is about ddos and iptable.
Whats the level of both applications iptables and load balancer,
is iptable is proceeded before load balancer ?!
By the way is there any anti ddos capability on google plateform?
I just ran into pricing calculator, 3TO incomming traffic with a load balancer cost 56 dols..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit a firewall , see this section https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls

Answer (score 1):

1. GCP ingress firewall is after loadbalancer
2. GCP load balancing solution has a DDoS mitigation built-in lowering the attack surface:

   - network load balancing has port filtering. Any port that is not loadbalanced is dropped by GCP highly scaling frontend infrastructure
   - HTTP/HTTPS loadbalancing can absorb and protect from IP spoofing and large SYN flood attacks.
   - it has also fair-share allocation built-in